# Trato de hacer un formulario que al completarse agrege los datos a una lista en html, con JSP y servlet , pero me aparece un error con el iterator nul

Tags: java, jsp

mi index.jsp

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>
> <head>
>     <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
>     <title>Insert title here</title>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <h1>Datos Personas</h1>
>     <form action="/ServletControllerPersona" method="post">
>         <label>Nombre</label>
>         <input type="text" name="nombre">
>         <label>Apelllido</label>
>         <input type="text" name="apellido">
>         <label>Edad</label>
>         <input type="text" name="edad">
>         <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
>     </form>       <%          List<Persona> lista = (List<Persona>) request.getAttribute("ListaPersonas");            Iterator<Persona> item=
> ```
>
> lista.iterator();         %>
>
> ```
>           <th>Nombre</th>         <th>Apellido</th>       <th>Edad</th>       </tr>
>           <% while(item.hasNext()) {
>         Persona = (Persona) item.next();
>     %>        <tr>        <td><%=p.getNombre() %></td>        <td><%=p.getApellido() %></td>      <td><%=p.getEdad() %></td>      </tr>
>     <% }%>        </table>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

el controlador es este,

> ```
> public class ServletControllerPersona extends HttpServlet {   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>    
> /**
>  * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
>  */
> public ServletControllerPersona() {
>     super();
>     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
> }
> ```
>
> /**      * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
> HttpServletResponse response)      */     protected void
> doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
> ServletException, IOException {       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
> response.getWriter().append("Served at:
> ").append(request.getContextPath());  }
>
> /**      * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
> HttpServletResponse response)      */     protected void
> doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
> throws ServletException, IOException {        // TODO Auto-generated method
> stub      //doGet(request, response);         int edad;       String
> nombre,apellido;      try {       nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
> apellido =request.getParameter("apellido");         edad
> =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("edad"));      ListListaPersonas = new ArrayList();      Persona
> persona = new Persona();              persona.setNombre(nombre);
> persona.setApellido(apellido);      persona.setEdad(edad);
> ListaPersonas.add(persona);
>
> ```
>           request.setAttribute("ListaPersonas",ListaPersonas);        RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
> ```
>
> request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
> dispatcher.forward(request, response);
>
> ```
>   }catch (Exception e) {          // TODO: handle exception
>       e.printStackTrace();        }   }
> ```

y este es mi modelo

> ```
> package modelo;
> ```
>
> public class Persona {    private String nombre;  private String
> apellido;     private int edad;       public Persona() {
> }
>
> public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, int edad) {      super();
> this.nombre = nombre;       this.apellido = apellido;       this.edad =
> edad;     }
>
> public String getNombre() {         return nombre;  }
>
> public void setNombre(String nombre) {      this.nombre = nombre;   }
>
> public String getApellido() {       return apellido;    }
>
> public void setApellido(String apellido) {      this.apellido =
> apellido;     }
>
> public int getEdad() {      return edad;    }
>
> public void setEdad(int edad) {         this.edad = edad;   }

me aparece el siguiente error

> may. 10, 2022 11:08:46 A. M.
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE: El
> Servlet.service() para el servlet [jsp] en el contexto con ruta
> [/LISTA_NOMBRES] lanzó la excepción [Ha sucedido una excepción al
> procesar la página JSP [/index.jsp] en línea [30]
>
> 27:          28:       <% 29:          List lista =
> (List) request.getAttribute("ListaPersonas"+1);   30:
> Iterator item= lista.iterator(); 31:       %> 32:      
> 33:
>
> Stacktrace:] con causa raíz java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
> invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "lista" is null    at
> org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:155)  at
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
> jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)    at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
> at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
> at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:867)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1716)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.